# What is the best way to use JavaScript modules on Server and Browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I'm currently building an JavaScript project that uses NodeJS and some objects are shared between client and server side.
I was trying to use the module system on node but I couldn't find a suitable implementation of the node modules on the browser.
Currently my test architecture is like this:

Framework.js (just creating a common namespace and some functions that the whole framework should know. It is on folder named Shared)

```
var Framework = {};
exports.Framework = Framework;
```

Module.js (Part of the framework responsible for a specific part)

```
var fw = require('../Shared/Module.js');
fw.Module = function() {};
exports.Framework = fw;
```

These modules go on and on.
I tried using a simple common.js implementation found on the web but it had some bugs on the scope created by the module. I also tried the idea shown on this post  http://caolanmcmahon.com/posts/writing_for_node_and_the_browser although it doesn't work, since I have to require the base object in my modules which wouldn't work on the browser.

How should I structure this code in a way that I can organize my code having different modules on different files to use (some of them) in server and browser?

Comment: Use browserify to package node modules and handle dependencies. As for architecture look at [ExpressArchTest](https://github.com/Raynos/ExpressArchTest)

Comment: had the same problem @filaruina, and browserify and requirejs were either too complex or used a slightly different api.  I put together [tiny-require.js](https://github.com/viatropos/tiny-require.js) which is pretty much node.js's require for the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are JavaScript module libraries that both work on browsers and Node. One example: [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org):

> RequireJS is a JavaScript file and module loader. It is optimized for
>   in-browser use, but it can be used in other JavaScript environments,
>   like Rhino and Node.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen RequireJS but its syntax is quite different from the NodeJS approach. I think I'll use it anyways.